# What server configuration and database should I use?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new to Database's and want to work toward installing a Database in the small company I work at for production and eventually other uses. The company has only 15 employee's and three departments. There will not be more than five computers accessing the database.

Currently the setup is one physical Domain Controller/file server running windows server 2012 r2 standard. This is a small warehouse that has many part numbers with instructions and pictures, all in multiple books. The office uses quick books and spreadsheets.

My goal is to have each department to access each job by sales order which will pull up all the items instructions, procedures and specifications for the job as it pertains to the department and eventually track production and inventory.

I will appreciate any assistance or guidance and I know there is much to learn but I am willing to take my time and build it in a virtual network for testing.

My thoughts on how and what database to use based on a small company and small budget.

1. Using SQL Server Express because has more storage than Access and would be scalable, secure, and cost effective. Is this correct?
2. Installing the SQL Server Express on the Domain Controller because it is a small company and would be cost effective and more simple. I am not sure if this is correct and if this is not recommended can I enable Hyper V on the Domain Controller and install server 2012 again using the same product key without having licensing issues in order to run the server for the database.

If there is more information needed then I will give it and I appreciate any advice and guidance.

I am a student while working and just started Database Design class and have a long way to go but I learn better when I am trying to build something in a real world application. I am willing to make mistakes it the virtual network in order to learn but not in my companies network. I believe I need a Database mentor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This site](http://dba.stackexchange.com), is a question and answer site, **not a mentoring site.**

You are already taking a Database Design class, which is much closer to the mentoring that you are seeking.  Also, you must have instruction materials that will explain at least the basics.

Questions are welcome, but you will get better results by:

1. Working on the problem yourself first.
2. Describe briefly your overall project.
3. Focus on one or two points, not a sweeping discussion of your project.
4. Clearly describing the problem that you are currently trying to resolve **and what you have already tried.**

General questions about databases, costs, et cetera are things that you need to study up on in advance. You must know the basics or your questions will get little useful response.

Search [DBA Stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com) and other sites to see what answers are already available to you.  You often **just need to search.**

Specific responses:

1. SQL Server Express 2014 can be a fine, fully featured database server.  It does not have all the auxiliary tools that the more expensive editions.  There are limitations: only uses one CPU, no single database can be bigger than 10 GB, the use of memory is limited, and so forth.
2. It is better to keep the domain controller and the SQL Server on separate machines, even if virtual, because of the increased exposure to security problems.

Your goal to create a simple system for a small group of users is a fine place to start.  You will learn a lot in the process that will help prepare you for bigger tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will set my virtual network up running windows server 2012 r2 running hyper V role with 2 vm's one being the domain controller and the other being sql server 2014 express. I will research it more and I am excited about learning and preparing for bigger tasks. Thanks again